# Explanation of packed attribute in C

Tags: c, compilation

I was wondering if anyone could offer a more full explanation to the meaning of the packed attribute used in the bitmap example in pset4.

> "Our use, incidentally, of the attribute called packed ensures that clang does not try to "word-align" members (whereby the address of each member’s first byte is a multiple of 4), `lest we end up with "gaps" in our structs that don’t actually exist on disk."`

I do not understand the comment around gaps in our structs. Does this refer to gaps in the memory location between each struct (i.e. one byte between each 3 byte RGB if it was to word-algin)? Why does this matter in for optimization?

```
typedef uint8_t BYTE;
typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;
```

Comment: What is the type of `BYTE` —  `uint8_t`, or  `unsigned char` or something else? There won't be any padding or alignment in the structure in any sane (commercially viable) compiler if the type maps to an 8-bit type. If you're on a DSP where `CHAR_BIT == 16`,then packing won't help anyway (and there still won't be any padding between the bytes; they'll just be 16 bits long instead of 8 bits). IMO, the precaution is a fantasy or phobia without a basis in reality. I'd certainly need a carefully documented counter-example to believe that there's an actual problem that the attribute helps with.

Comment: I was led to believe that you could encounter issues when you pass the entire struct to a function like fread as it assumes you're giving it an array like chunk of memory, with no gaps in it. If your struct has gaps, the first byte ends up in the right place, but the next two bytes get written in the gap, which you don't have a proper way to access.

Comment: Sorta...but mostly no.  The issue is that the values in the padding bytes are indeterminate.  However, in the structure shown, assuming an 8-bit `BYTE` type, there will be no padding in any compiler I've come across; the structure will be 3 bytes long.  There is no reason to put any padding anywhere inside the structure (between elements) or after the last element (and the standard prohibits padding before the first element).  So, in this context, there is no issue — IMO, of course.

Comment: If you write binary data to a file and it has holes in it, then you get arbitrary byte values written where the holes are.  If you read back on the same (type of) machine, there won't actually be a problem.  If you read back on a different (type of) machine, there may be problems — hence my [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635235/explanation-of-packed-attribute-in-c?noredirect=1#comment64658127_38635400) about serialization and deserialization.  I've only been programming in C a little over 30 years; I've never needed `packed`, and don't expect to.

Comment: Thanks, thats great info. This comes directly from the CS50 comp sci course (adapted from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922590.aspx), it seems unnecessarily confusing for a beginner style course. Would you consider creating an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>*Beware: prejudices on display!*</sup>

As noted in comments, when the compiler adds the padding to a structure, it does so to improve performance.  It uses the alignments for the structure elements that will give the best performance.

Not so very long ago, the DEC Alpha chips would handle a 'unaligned memory request' (`umr`) by doing a page fault, jumping into the kernel, fiddling with the bytes to get the required result, and returning the correct result.  This was painfully slow by comparison with a correctly aligned memory request; you avoided such behaviour at all costs.

Other RISC chips (used to) give you a SIGBUS error if you do misaligned memory accesses.  Even Intel chips have to do some fancy footwork to deal with misaligned memory accesses.

The purpose of removing padding is to (decrease performance but) benefit by being able to serialize and unserialize the data without doing the job 'properly' — it is a form of laziness that actually doesn't work properly when the machines communicating are not of the same type, so proper serialization should have been done in the first place.

What I mean is that if you are writing data over the network, it seems simpler to be able to send the data by writing the contents of a structure as a block of memory (error checking etc omitted):

```
write(fd, &structure, sizeof(structure));
```

The receiving end can read the data:

```
read(fd, &structure, sizeof(structure));
```

However, if the machines are of different types (for example, one has an Intel CPU and the other a SPARC or Power CPU), the interpretation of the data in those structures will vary between the two machines (unless every element of the array is either a `char` or an array of `char`).  To relay the information reliably, you have to agree on a byte order (e.g. network byte order — this is very much a factor in TCP/IP networking, for example), and the data should be transmitted in the agreed upon order so that both ends can understand what the other is saying.

You can define other mechanisms: you could use a 'sender makes right' mechanism, in which the 'receiver' let's the sender know how it wants the data presented and the sender is responsible for fixing up the transmitted data.  You can also use a 'receiver makes right' mechanism which works the other way around.  Both these have been used commercially — see [DRDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRDA) for one such protocol.

---

Given that the type of `BYTE` is `uint8_t`, there won't be any padding in the structure in any sane (commercially viable) compiler. IMO, the precaution is a fantasy or phobia without a basis in reality. I'd certainly need a carefully documented counter-example to believe that there's an actual problem that the attribute helps with.

> I was led to believe that you could encounter issues when you pass the entire struct to a function like `fread` as it assumes you're giving it an array like chunk of memory, with no gaps in it. If your struct has gaps, the first byte ends up in the right place, but the next two bytes get written in the gap, which you don't have a proper way to access.

Sorta...but mostly no. The issue is that the values in the padding bytes are indeterminate. However, in the structure shown, there will be no padding in any compiler I've come across; the structure will be 3 bytes long. There is no reason to put any padding anywhere inside the structure (between elements) or after the last element (and the standard prohibits padding before the first element). So, in this context, there is no issue.

If you write binary data to a file and it has holes in it, then you get arbitrary byte values written where the holes are. If you read back on the same (type of) machine, there won't actually be a problem. If you read back on a different (type of) machine, there may be problems — hence my comments about serialization and deserialization. I've only been programming in C a little over 30 years; I've never needed packed, and don't expect to.  (And yes, I've dealt with serialization and deserialization using a standard layout — the system I mainly worked on used big-endian data transfer, which corresponds to [network byte order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, the elements of a struct are simply aligned to a 4-byte boundary (or whatever the size of a register is in the CPU) to optimize read/write access to RAM. Often, smaller elements are packed together, but alignment is dictated by a larger type in the struct.

In your case, you probably don't *need* to pack the struct, but it doesn't hurt.

With some compilers, each byte in your struct could end up taking 4 bytes of RAM *each* (so, 12 bytes for the entire struct). Packing the struct removes the alignment requirement for each of the BYTEs, and ensures that the entire struct is placed into one 4-byte DWORD (unless the alignment for the entire program is set to one byte, or the struct is in an array of said structs, in that case it would literally be stored in 3 contiguous bytes of RAM).

See comments below for further discussion...

Comment: Not exactly...You said "Usually the elements of a struct are aligned to a 4-byte boundary" but that's not so.  Usually, an N-byte element in a structure is aligned to an N-byte boundary (for simple elements; arrays are aligned according to the alignment requirement of the elements of the array).

Comment: Ah, "usually" is definitely the wrong word. Your assertion that N-byte elements are N-byte aligned is incorrect. That would mean that packing is unnecessary. Consider the following: `typedef struct { int w; char x; short y; char z; } XXX;`. This struct is 12 bytes without packing, according to the compiler I'm using. Packed, it's 8. If N-byte alignment were used, the struct's size would be 9 bytes in both cases. In my example struct, overall alignment is dictated by the `int`, but the compiler 'optimizes' the chars by packing them into the same 4 byte dword. The short gets its own dword.

Comment: I used a 'Usually' in that assertion.  And you've managed to misinterpret what I mean — there isn't enough space in a single comment to write out the full explanation of N-byte aligned, but the size of 12 for your type `XXX` is what I'd expect and what is intended to be read into the shorthand.  The start of the next structure must be sufficiently well aligned that each of the N-byte quantities within it will be aligned; that demands the 3 bytes trailing padding after `z` that takes the total to 12.

Comment: Note that in `XXX`, `w` must be on a 4-byte boundary (making reasonable assumptions about type sizes — ILP32 or LP64 or LLP64); `x` will be on a 4-byte boundary but could be on any alignment; `y` will be on a 2-byte boundary so there's a padding byte between `x` and `y`; `z` is therefore on a 4-byte boundary, but the overall size must be a multiple of 4 because that is the strictest alignment required within the structure.  Change `y` to type `double` (from `short`) and you get size 24 — the alignment must be a multiple of 8, with 3 bytes padding after `x` and 7 bytes padding after `z`.

Comment: Some x86 variants manage to allow `double` (size 8) on a 4-byte rather than 8-byte boundary.  'Usually' is the operative term — the details always depend on the system.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to *my* use of the word "usually", not yours. ;) But, we're essentially in agreement, I think.

Comment: OK; that's fine — I can live with that.  I wasn't quite clear on why you thought the N-byte alignment rule would give a size of 9 ever; it wouldn't, as I tried to explain in the copious prior response comments.

Comment: Yep. Didn't say a compiler would *actually* produce a 9-byte struct. But with strict, hypothetical me being a pain in the ass because I'm pedantic, N-byte alignment: `|xxxx|x| |xx|x|` where the space is padding to align the y on a 2-byte boundary.  xD

Comment: You PITA mode layout doesn't work because the N-byte alignment rules must ensure that every element of an array of the type is properly aligned, which is why you get trailing padding at all.  So, to ensure N-byte alignment when the maximum N is 4, the size of the overall structure _must_ be a multiple of N.  Otherwise, the elements of `XXX name[10];` after `name[0]` won't all be properly aligned, defeating the objective of adding padding bytes anywhere in the first place.  Like I said, it's a bit much to condense to 600 characters — or a single comment.

Comment: And my earlier statement: "the compiler 'optimizes' the chars by packing them into the same 4 byte dword" was incorrect. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score -1):

The objective is exactly what you said, not having gaps between each struct. Why is this important? Mostly because of cache. Memory access is slow!!! Cache is really fast. If you can fit more in cache you avoid cache misses (memory accesses).

**Edit:** Seems I was wrong, didn't seem really useful if the objective was structure padding since the struct has 3 BYTE

Comment: So two structs that are created would be in contiguous memory? Or is it members within the struct that are in contiguous memory.

Comment: Actually this is wrong. The `packed` attribute eliminates spaces *inside* the struct. In this case, it ensures that the struct has a size of 3 bytes. When optimizing for speed, the compiler may choose to store each of these struct elements using 32 bits so it doesn't have to do time-consuming bit masking to extract their values. However, this will cause problems when the struct is written to a file or other device that is expecting to receive only 3 bytes.

Comment: The members would be always contiguous since they're all the same type -> BYTE and BYTE should be 8bits (For more information search about structure padding). So it would be only useful if more structures would be contiguous in memory

Comment: The purpose of the compiler when it adds the padding is to improve performance — it uses the alignments that will give the best performance.  The purpose of removing padding it is to decrease performance but benefit by being able to serialize and unserialize the data without doing the job 'properly' — it is a form of laziness that actually doesn't work properly when the machines communication are not of the same type, so proper serialization should have been done in the first place.